# C# Reentrant lock with cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex, monitor

I need a synchronization object that allows me to lock recursively with the same thread and that has a `Wait(CancellationToken)` method. Only one thread should be able to acquire the lock at the same time. The following do not suit my needs, so I am asking here:

`Monitor` - does not have a `Wait(CancellationToken)` method

`lock (_lock)` - does use monitor internally, does not have a `Wait(CancellationToken)` method

`SemaphoreSlim` - does not allow reentrancy only for current thread, if I set the count to more than 1, two threads can acquire the lock at the same time

`Mutex` - does not allow reentrancy

Is there any built-in synchronization class to achieve this or do I have to write one on my own?

Comment: You say "same thread" but then you mention cancellation tokens. You do know that tasks can flow across multiple threads during their lifetime, right? Can you explain if you actually mean "same task"?

Comment: note: if you're talking about `CancellationToken`, you're *probably* talking about async, and if you're dealing with async, you need to stop thinking of things as *threads*, because: the thread isn't reliable/known/constant with async; mostly saying this because it impacts any design choices you might make for detecting reentrancy; however! frankly, the better option here is: tweak your code to not take the lock in a reentrant way

Comment: I am not using tasks at all only Threads. I am using CancellationToken when one thread want to notify the other thread that it should cancel its work

Comment: It is not ideal but you could use the [`Monitor.TryEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter) with a short timeout in a loop, and check the `CancellationToken` on every loop.